# How to close TCP connection from server in Java

Tags: java, tcp, server

Here is use case I need to implement in Java:

1. Server is listening for push messages from some clients
2. If client has some data to push into server, it opens TCP connection and sends all messages
3. When client sends last message (special message saying that this is the last one) server should close connection by starting TCP closing handshake

I have problem with last step because I don't know how to close connection from server site. My current code is bellow. How to initiate connection closing TCP handshake form server site? Thank you for any help.

```
public class Server{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    while (true) {
        int port = AppConfig.getInstance().getPort();

        try (ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(port)) {
            Socket server = socket.accept();

            InetAddress ipAddress = server.getInetAddress();

            MessageHandler handler = new MessageHandler(ipAddress);

            InputStream in = server.getInputStream();

            // reads all bytes from input stream and process them by given handler
            processStream(in, handler);
            in.close();

            server.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LoggingUtils.logException(e);
        }   
    }
}

private static void processStream(InputStream in, MessageHandler handler) throws Exception {
    // implementation is omitted
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done it. `in.close()` closes the input stream, the socket output stream, and the socket.

What you should really close is whatever output stream was attached to the socket, to ensure it gets flushed, and you should probably do that in the `processStream()` method, with a saver `server .close()` in a `finally` block in the calling method.

NB Your socket names are really the wrong way round. It is customary to use `ServerSocket serverSocket`, and `Socket socket = serverSocket.accept()`.

Answer (score 0):

I may be not totally sure about this one, but I would believe that socket.close() will send all the commands (FIN/FIN-ACK)